# Windows 7 Application using Internet Explorer to render web page

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer

An application running on Windows 7 is breaking when it tries to render Google Maps.

When I load the URL into Internet Explorer it fails, when I load it via Chrome it works. I have tried to turn off Internet Explorer via "Turn Windows features on or off" and also Windows Default Programs (IE not showing on the list).

Set Default Programs is showing Google Chrome (and Firefox)

When I go to Set Program Access and Computer Defaults. Under Choose a default web browser , it selected as "Use my current Web browser", I have tried changing this to Google Chrome but when I open the menu again it returns to the default.

I have added a link within a spreadsheet document and when I click it - it takes me to Google Chrome.

I've also tried renaming the folder for Internet Explorer "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer IS A VIRUS"

Is there anything else that I can try?

Comment: Try installing Chromium Edge for Windows 7 and see if then, the default changes to Chromium Edge. I still have a Windows 7 VM and that is the only browser I use

Comment: IE is outdated by years, that's why it does not work.

Comment: @Moab but which is the program using IE?

Comment: @John I tried that but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Windows 7 is getting long past old, so it may be time to try a newer operating system.

Comment: I have specific programs that run under W7. I'm not sure how easier it would be to upgrade.

Comment: "
Windows 7 is getting long past old, so it may be time to try a newer operating system. – 
John" ••• This sentiment is simply obtuse when one considers how many "old" things is in one's life. Be reasonable, man! WHAT IS... "OLD"... just because YOU do not have the alacrity to utilize something "OLD". I sense a personal verve, and not a legitimate declaration of fact here... *chuckle*. Cheers, John, and all the very best to you and yours...